# Cant echo multiple values in array

Tags: php, echo

I have something like this in my code:

```
<?php 
foreach ($tomb2[1] as $key => $metaname){
    $talalat = $tomb[1][$key]; 
    echo '<p>' . "$metaname\n" . '</p>' . '<br>' . '<input type="text" name="metavalue[]" value="' . "$talalat\n" . '">' . '<br>';
}
?>    
<input type="submit" name="Generálás" value="insert" onclick="insert()" />
</form>
```

I try to echo the several different values, however I get only the last one. Possibly the array contains only the last one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you `print_r($tomb2)`?

Comment: yes, that part is okay. My problem is when I try to do something like this: $ertekek = $_GET["metavalue"];
 echo $ertekek; . I also tried foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a post method in form then you have to written $ertekek = $_POST["metavalue"] instead of $_GET["metavalue"] and then use print_r($ertekek)
instead of echo $ertekek;

Comment: what is $tomb variable contains?

Answer (score 1):

You have written `$talalat = $tomb[1][$key];` instead of `$talalat = $tomb2[1][$key];`

Comment: That part is completely ok and working. I have the other problem I mentioned in my other comment.

Comment: Is the action on your form set to `get` or absent and not set to `post`? Also if you look at the source of your page is it showing properly?